# Compactification of log z Riemann Surface

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, compactness, riemann-surfaces, compact-manifolds

I've been reading the 'Road to Reality' book of Roger Penrose and in the chapter on Riemann Surfaces, there is a note that we can compactify the log z Riemann Surface into a sphere. But I don't see the way to do it and find any clues in literature. Maybe, someone here knows the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because $z\to \log z+2ik\pi$ is locally biholomorphic the Riemann surface of $\log z$ is just $\{ \log z + 2i k\pi, z\in \Bbb{C}^*\}= \Bbb{C}$ its compactification is the Riemann surface $\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$

Comment: I don't understand why Riemann Surface of log z = ℂ?
It looks like it just covers ℂ in a lot of layers. So, we can only project it to ℂ.

Comment: and could we glue the Riemann surface into sphere explicitly somehow? so I will be able to draw it?